# Reset 'Automatically generated passwords for new entires'

Tags: keepass

I have accidentally overwritten the default password generation value in Keepass2. What pattern matches the original default value? I have tried `[A!#$%&*+-/:;=?@^_~]{16}` but this produces passwords of ~97 bits quality whereas the default produced ~107 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These should be the default settings for automatically generated passwords in KeePass, unless you adjusted them:

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, I was making it more complicated than necessary, adding in extra characters!